# Get random data from firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I'd like to get any random data from a firebase tree

Firebase data structure

```
grabbit

    active

       category (womenClothes, womenBags, womenShoes etc)
```

how do I grab and random dataset from http://gamerholic.firebaseio.com/grabbit/active/

if doesn't matter what the category is, it just want it to pick one get get me that data much like i'd do a rand() in php

Comment: Can you put a litte example of the tree with some data? The link to firebase seems not work

Comment: http://gamerholic.firebaseio.com/grabbit/active/

Comment: I can't see anything, it said that my user is not allowed to see the database.

Comment: Answer covered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990206/pick-random-value-from-firebase-snapshot/